# Moving an Ellipse Object from left to right smoothly in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an `MyEllipe` class that extends `CStatic`.

I have my own custom `OnPaint` method body that overrides.

And i have a method to move this object in a dialog to move from left to right:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 600; i++) {
   myEllipseObject->SetWindowPos(NULL, i, 300, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
   Sleep(1);
}
```

So, basically it moves one by one with 1 miliseconds delay.. Is it work? Yes. Is it correct? I doubt it :). So, what is the correct and valid way of doing this? I have one ellipse and one rectangle that i want to move from left to right when user click to button.

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would usually do this with a timer. For example, you might set a timer, and update the position when the timer fires. You can either respond to the [`WM_TIMER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644902.aspx) message, or specify a function for it to call when the timer fires.